# How do I build a relation of users having a specific role, automatically?

Tags: entities

I have installed the [Relation](http://drupal.org/project/relation) module. I need that users with the "test" role are related with all users having the "student" role, automatically.

How can I build this relation?

Comment: It's worth pointing out that _roles_, can be neither target nor source in a relation. _Users_ of the "test" role can however. Please re-phrase and I will up-vote.

Comment: Is the question better, now?

Answer (score 2):

With the Rules module, you could take action on a "user created with role student" event.

Comment: This is precisely the reason we added Rules support.